# Show next date based on criteria

Tags: mysql, perl, datetime

In perl I have the following database query:

```
   my $list = $db->SelectARef("SELECT p.*, u.usr_login, u.usr_money, u.usr_email, u.usr_pay_email, u.usr_pay_type
                           FROM Payments p, Users u
                           WHERE status='PENDING'
                           AND p.usr_id=u.usr_id
                           ORDER BY u.usr_pay_type");
```

Within the array result there is a field named "created".

What I want to do is add another element to the array for each row as "next payment".

Payments are processed after 30 full days from the datetime value but only on the 6th day of every month. Basically I want each result to have a "next payment" element stating which day and month they should get paid on.

e.g created = 2013-07-29 18:55:37
30 days from this is the 28th August 2013
Therefore the next payment date would be the 6th September

I have no idea where to start with this, any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following shows the logic:

```
select (date(t) - interval (day(t) - 1) day) + interval 1 month + interval 5 day
from (select cast(now() as datetime) as t) t;
```

You can put this into your query as:

```
SELECT p.*, u.usr_login, u.usr_money, u.usr_email, u.usr_pay_email, u.usr_pay_typel,
       created - interval (day(created) - 1) day) + interval 1 month + interval 5 day as nextpay
FROM Payments p join
     Users u
     on p.usr_id=u.usr_id
WHERE status='PENDING' 
ORDER BY u.usr_pay_type;
```

The expression can be simplified to:

```
       created - interval (day(created) + 4) day) + interval 1 month as nextpay
```

Comment: I can't see how that would give the next pay date or have I missed something? It looks like it just had a month on to me?

Comment: @papa_face . . . Did you run the first query?  It returns the 6th day of the next month.

Comment: my $list = $db->SelectARef("SELECT p.*, u.usr_login, u.usr_money, u.usr_email, u.usr_pay_email, u.usr_pay_type, p.created - interval (day(p.created) + 4) day) + interval 1 month as nextpay
                               FROM Payments p, Users u
                               WHERE status='PENDING'
                               AND p.usr_id=u.usr_id
                               ORDER BY u.usr_pay_type");

I get this error:
syntax to use near ') + interval 1 month as nextpay
                               FROM Payments p, ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to compute a `next_payment` date which is the nearest 6th day of a month that is at least 30 days from the `created` date.  Another way of saying that is that your due date is always the 6th of the month with at least a 30 day grace period from the close date.

Unfortunately, we can't do a simple rounding or stepping here, because the Gregorian calendar isn't quite a regular series.  (It quite isn't a regular series?)  So, we'll put conditional logic into a query.  As this looks just awful, we'll hide it in a function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION next_payment(close_date DATE)
RETURNS DATE
  DETERMINISTIC
  READS SQL DATA
  LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE min_grace INT  DEFAULT 30; -- minimum grace period of 30 days
  DECLARE bill_dom  INT  DEFAULT  6; -- billing day of month is the 6th
  DECLARE d         DATE;

  SET d = close_date + INTERVAL min_grace DAY;

  IF DAY(d) > bill_dom THEN                    -- Did 30 days\' grace put us beyond the 6th?
    SET d = d + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;              -- If so, advance to next month.
  END IF;

  RETURN d + INTERVAL(bill_dom - DAY(d)) DAY;  -- Now "round" to the 6th of the month
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

How you use the logic is up to you.  Adding `SELECT next_payment(p.created) AS "next_payment", ...` will give you the additional column you want.  You could parameterize the above (e.g., `CREATE FUNCTION next_payment(close_date DATE, min_grace INT, bill_dom INT)`) for greater flexibility.  You might rip the SET/IF logic out of the function and jam it into one unwieldy CASE/END statement in your SELECT.  You could create a VIEW that automatically "appends" a `next_payment` column to the table, or ALTER TABLE and populate a new column, etc.